# Equivalent code in Python to PHP

Tags: php, python

I need the equivalent code for this python code in PHP. 
`val` would be a string containing two words seperated by a "-" and the code would separate them into two different strings

Here is the Python Code:

```
def function(val) :
    s= False
    ar = ""
    so = ""
    For x in val : 
        if s == true : 
            x.append(so)
        elif x <> "-" : 
            x.append(ar)
        elif x == "-" :
            s= true
```

Comment: Looks like you need code to do that in Python, too, because the given snippet is nothing but syntax errors, typos, and other oddities (`x <> "-"`?).

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = explode('-', $val);
```

$result contains an array of strings, split at the hyphen, i.e. $result[0], etc

http://php.net/explode

Answer (score 0):

```
function func($val)
{
    if(!strpos($val,'-')) return false;
    $vars   =   explode('-',$val);
    return array($vars[0],$vars[1]);
}
```